# How to set CRM javascript value to null?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, null, dynamics-crm, crm

I have the following JavaScript code in a Dynmaics library, however the code does not set the value to null in the else condition any ideas to why? I believe my code is correct.

Please advise. My null setting isnt working I also tried `removeAttribute();`it does not work

```
    function validateSortCode(executionContext) {
        
        var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
        
        var sortcode = formContext.getAttribute("sortcodee").getValue();
        
        var errorId = "error";
        
        if(sortcode != "")
        
        {
            var sortcoderegex = /^(\d){2}-(\d){2}-(\d){2}$/;
            if(sortcoderegex.test(sortcode) == false)
            {
                formContext.ui.setFormNotification("Please ensure correct format of Sort Code i.e. 12-34-56", "ERROR", errorId);
            }
            else
            {
    
    formContext.getAttribute("sortcodee").setValue(null);
 //formContext.getAttribute("sortcodee").removeAttribute("sortcodee");

            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: The removeAttribute method does not exist according to microsofts docs. Depending on the fields format, the setValue() method will expect a certain datatype. Is there any error thrown?

Comment: @MerlinFejzuli their is no error thrown, it just doesnt clear the value

Comment: Did you debug? Do you have any onChange event on that field to trigger?

Comment: But you're explicitly checking that there is no value set and then trying to set the value to  null. What is the problem with the empty String? The docs would suggest that the setValue() method is anticipating the value to be of the same type as the attribute field.

Comment: what do you suggest as answers? @MerlinFejzuli

Comment: Please advise @ArunVinoth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value after your notification of the error to null.

Try this.

```
function validateSortCode(executionContext) {
    
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    
    var sortcode = formContext.getAttribute("sortcodee").getValue();
    
    var errorId = "error";
    
    if(sortcode != "")
    
    {
        var sortcoderegex = /^(\d){2}-(\d){2}-(\d){2}$/;
        if(sortcoderegex.test(sortcode) == false)
        {
            formContext.ui.setFormNotification("Please ensure correct format of Sort Code i.e. 12-34-56", "ERROR", errorId);

formContext.getAttribute("sortcodee").setValue("");

        }
        else
        {

formContext.ui.clearFormNotification(errorId);

        }
   }
}
```

The above should do the trick